# Is it acceptable to receive payment from U.S. in Indian saving bank account via PayPal?

Tags: india, money-transfer, online-payment, paypal

I'm working as a MyCommerce - RegNow affiliate. I promote software/desktop utilities of various software vendors associated with MyCommerce and they pay me some commission for each sale. MyCommerce process the payment on the 1st of each month for sales in the previous month and transfer the total commission in USD to my PayPal account, then I withdraw the money in my Indian saving bank account. I earn approx. 2.50 lakhs (4041 USD) per month. Is it fine to receive that much money in a saving bank account or should I open a current/business account for receiving my commission? Is having too much money in a saving account can also cause problems?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Nicks I am doing the same thing as you are doing. Would like to know what did you find out about the service tax?
I am looking into this and trying to search if the work we do comes under "Export of Service" or no. Would surely share my thoughts with you as I find out more about it. Have consulted about 2 -3 CAs and still dont have a straight answer to this.

Answer (score 3):

It is fine to receive payments into Indian Savings Bank account. There are no restriction on deposits. There are only restrictions on number of withdrawls in a quarter.

A Current[a.k.a Checking] account makes it easier to manage.

You haven't asked about tax, but I you may already know you would need to pay taxes irrespective of whether you got the money in Savings or Current account.

Edit:
Any individual can open a Current Account on individual's name. There is no restriction.

There are multiple aspects to determine whether the activity you are doing is a service as defined by the Service Tax Rules. Please consult a CA to guide you. For less than 5K INR he would not only advice you but also do everything required to file taxes.

Comment: Honestly, I was hoping to get a reply from you, thanks! 

Can I open a current account without any Entity Proof like service tax registration certificate. I do pay my income tax but I do not pay any service tax. Is the activities I'm doing to earn affiliate commission fall under "Export of Services?" Last year my gross income was around 25 Lakhs. Do I also need to pay the service tax?